# Manipulate post data across the whole site in laravel

Tags: laravel, post

What is best practice to manipulate posted data across the whole site in laravel ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: I want to change number format from arabic to english format , for example I want to change number ۳ to 3 in every form that post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/middleware) that updates the incoming `Request` and register it globally by appending it to the `$middleware` array of your `Http\Kernel`

Answer (score 1):

```
function convert($string) {
    $persianDigits= array('۰', '۱', '۲', '۳', '۴', '۵', '۶', '۷', '۸', '۹');
    $arabicDigits= array('٩', '٨', '٧', '٦', '٥', '٤', '٣', '٢', '١', '٠');
    $allPersianDigits=array_merge($persinaDigits, $arabicDigits);
    $replaces = range(0,9);
    return str_replace($allPersianDigits, $replaces , $string);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but my question is where to put this code to convert automatically all of posted data , not to convert manually